Keycloack Custom Identity provider
I'm trying to create a new idp for my purposes.
I created all, it get shown on "identity providers" and i can enable it, so on login screen i see my new Idp.
I implemented "performLogin" to do a redirect to my service, then my service redirect back to keycloak with some query data that i will read on "callback" implemented as "Endpoint".
I can get all i need from "callback", i can create a new user from that, assign a role etc
What i'm missing is to authenticate the user:
session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession() // it's empty
callback.getAndVerifyAuthenticationSession() // I'm unable to make it work

Some help?
Seems like i have to return a "BrokeredIdentityContext identity" in "return callback.authenticated(identity)" after set an AuthenticationSessionModel.

You are right. If you implement your callback e.g., like this:
class MyIdentityProvider extends AbstractIdentityProvider<IdentityProviderModel> {

    ....

    @Override
    public Object callback(RealmModel realm, org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityProvider.AuthenticationCallback callback, EventBuilder event) {
      return new MyAuthenticationEndpoint(realm, callback, event, this, session);
    }

}

you can do all sorts of stuff in MyAuthenticationEndpoint, but you have to create a BrokeredIdentityContext:
@GET
public Response handleMyResponse(
    @QueryParam("state") String state,
    @QueryParam("parameter1") String parameter1,
    @QueryParam("parameter2") String parameter2,
    @QueryParam("parameter2") String parameter3
) {
  // your service has to provide the keycloak's state back, once finished with the processing, so keycloak can pick it up again
  AuthenticationSessionModel authenticationSessionModel = this.callback.getAndVerifyAuthenticationSession(state);
  // Retrieve all kinds of data from our service in order to create the (new) user    

  BrokeredIdentityContext brokerContext = new BrokeredIdentityContext(theUserId);
  brokerContext.setAuthenticationSession(authenticationSessionModel);
  brokerContext.setIdpConfig(myIdentityProvider.getConfig());
  brokerContext.setIdp(myIdentityProvider);
  brokerContext.setToken(theTokenFromMyService);

  return callback.authenticated(brokerContext);
}


I was totally skipping the "state" part, so I wasn't carrying state to callback.
So there was no parameter for getAndVerifyAuthenticationSession.
Thanks!
